# Wordpress removing <a> from one menu item

Tags: html, wordpress

Under my contact menu I have a dynamicly generated telephone number using http://www.responsetap.com 
analysis software and all is fine in all browsers except Safari on iPhone where it seems to be adding an additional `<a>` tag and displaying both the dynamically generated phone number and the fall back phone number...

Now the question is: Can I remove the `<a>` tag from this menu item and only this menu item completely since the JavaScript they supply seems to add one anyway?

This is the current code generated in chrome:

```
<li id="menu-item-1372" class="cmi_menu_item_1372 menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1372"><a>Call Us <span class="rTapNumber23746">0800 612 9481 </span></a></li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**dirty way:**
create a 'custom link' that goes to `href="#"`, The `<a>` will be there but it won't do anything when clicked, I don't know how th Iphone will handle it.

**better way**
create a [custom walker](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/Walker_Class). And build your own exeption, which excludes the `<a>`

More information:

- [example](http://shinraholdings.com/62/custom-nav-menu-walker-function/#example-code)
- [tutorial](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/understanding-the-walker-class/)

Comment: Thank you Janw, I think the custom walker is the way to go with this. You've been a great help and solved the question :D